# Filling the column 3 of dataframe 1 on the basis of column 1 of dataframe 1 and column 2 of dataframe 2

Tags: pandas, dataframe, series

I have 2 dataframes df1 and df2. No any unique value and have different number of rows in both of them.
df1:

```
| code_IATA  | code_ICAO | Time_Zone        |

| ASGE       | BSF       | Pacific          |

| BEMDF      | NHU       | America/New_york |

| JKL        | STF       | America/New_york |
```

df2:

```
| code_IATA  | code_ICAO | Time_Zone |

| ASGE       | BSF       | NAN       |

| BEMDF      | NHU       | NAN       |

| POW        | UFT       | NAN       |

| SHMS       | LNQ       | NAN       |
```

I want to copy value of Time_Zone of df1 in Time_Zone of df2 where code_IATA value of both column match.
I tried map, contains and tried to resolve with for loop but can't able to do.

```
df2['Time_Zone '] = df2['code_IATA'].map(df1.set_index('code_IATA')['Time_Zone'])
```

I can't remove duplicate values because all values are important to me and df1 contains more rows then df2. Number of rows are not equal in both dataframes.

Hope, I explain well.

Comment: code_ICAO doesn't matter here? Can you add some duplicate rows to your example and the expected output?

Comment: I just wanna show there are some other columns too. But I need to compare code_IATA

Answer (score 0):

Try [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
new_df=df1.merge(df2,on='code_IATA',how='right').reindex(columns=['code_IATA','code_ICAO_y','Time_Zone_x'])
new_df.columns=df1.columns
print(new_df)
  code_IATA code_ICAO         Time_Zone
0      ASGE       BSF           Pacific
1     BEMDF       NHU  America/New_york
2       POW       UFT               NaN
3      SHMS       LNQ               NaN
```

---

or using with :`on=['code_IATA','code_ICAO']`

```
df1.merge(df2,how='right',on=['code_IATA','code_ICAO']).drop('Time_Zone_y',axis=1)
```

Comment: My code may not fit what you want. If not, try to create a somewhat more representative example :)